# Ubuntu Flash Drive Will Not Boot

Tags: boot, live-usb

I created a bootable flash drive using Windows 7, Pendrivelinux, and ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386. I tried booting from it after changing boot option in bios to USB. System shows no errors but boots in windows 7. I went to Disk Managment and the drive does not show up as bootable. Pendrivelinux completed showing no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use the tool named Universal usb from pendrive linux .com it works for me............